# transparent activity's full screen on 2.3

Tags: android

I was using this xml style:

```
<style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar">
```

This was showing a tansparent layout with full screen, no title bar or status bar on the top in android 2.1 and 2.2.
However, when I tested the application on 2.3, the same activity was showing the home screen status bar on the top (battery etc).

I had to enter these lines to my java code onCreate:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);     
 getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

To get it to remove any status or title bar from the top.

Can anybody shed light why this difference between 2.2 and 2.3?

Comment: Did you see this on a 2.3 device ? I cant get hold of a gingerbread, but if i do i'll surely try it out. Well if you did you can add this issue to the android buglist

Comment: Yes but only on the emulator which now can run on 2.3 as well. It seems that 2.3 emulator also has some tighter memory restrictions, it was giving an exception error when loading some big bitmaps which I had to reduce in size. This was not a problem on 2.1 and 2.2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the theme to:

`<style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">"`

And that should hide both the title bar and fullscreen in every version.

Answer (score 1):

> You Can Also Use This

```
 <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
```